# Selecting initial rows CoreTable

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I have a `<tr:table value="#{mybean.tableValue} binding="#{mybean.tableBinding}">`  that i want to show with the selection multiple enabled. 
I'm using a List for the collection and the values are take from database when i selected a value from a `<tr:selectManyCheckbox>` valueChangeListener with partial triggers.

For each row returned, if some value is true, i want this row marked as selected  in the `<tr:table value="#{mybean.tableValue} binding="#{mybean.tableBinding}">`

I think the problem is that my  binding value is not updating when the *valueChangeEvent* runs inspite of i put *binding.setValue* the results of database (i  checked that the `binding.getRowCount()` not equal than `mybean.tableValue.size()`) and then the values selected are not correct)

Any idea why the binding rowCount is not equal the value of table?

UPDATE:

```
<tr:subform id="subform1">
    <tr:panelFormLayout rows="6">
    <tr:selectManyCheckbox id="val1" label="Values"
      layout="horizontal" value="#{mybean.data1Values}" 
      autoSubmit="true" valueChangeListener="#{mybean.valuesChangeListener}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{mybean.list1Values}"/>
    </tr:selectManyCheckbox>                        
   </tr:panelFormLayout>
</tr:subform>
<tr:spacer width="5px"/>
<tr:subform id="subform2">            
    <tr:table rows="0" partialTriggers=":::subform1:val1 " 
      value="#{mybean.data2Values}" var="item" id="tabladatos" width="75%" 
      rowSelection="multiple" rowBandingInterval="1" binding="#{mybena.tableBinding}"
      verticalGridVisible="true" horizontalGridVisible="true">
    <tr:column id="_head1" headerText="Colum1" width="30%">
        <tr:outputText id="_head1_value" value="#{item.value1}"/>
    </tr:column>
    <tr:column id="_head2" headerText="Colum2" width="30%">
        <tr:outputText id="_head2_value" value="#{item.value2}"/>
    </tr:column>                
    </tr:table>        
</tr:subform>

public void valuesChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event != null) {
            List<Integer> valores = (List<Integer>) event.getNewValue();
            data2Values.addAll(databaseDAO.search(valores));
            RowKeySet rks = new RowKeySetImpl();
            rks.clear();
            tableBinding.setSelectedRowKeys(rks);
            tableBinding.setValue(data2Values);
            for (int x = 0; x < tableBinding.getRowCount(); x++) {
                dataEntity row = (dataEntity) tableBinding.getRowData(x);
                tableBinding.setRowIndex(x);
                if (row.isTrue()) {
                    Object key = tableBinding.getRowKey();
                    rks.add(key);//tableBinding.getSelectedRowKeys().add(key);
                } else {
                    //do something
                }
            }
            tableBinding.setVar("item");
            tableBinding.setSelectedRowKeys(rks);
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.renderResponse();
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I changed the valueChangeListener:

```
public void valuesChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event != null) {
            List<Integer> valores = (List<Integer>) event.getNewValue();
            data2Values.addAll(databaseDAO.search(valores));
            tableBinding.getSelectedRowKeys().clear;
            tableBinding.setValue(data2Values);
            for (int x = 0; x < tableBinding.getRowCount(); x++) {
                dataEntity row = (dataEntity) tableBinding.getRowData(x);
                tableBinding.setRowIndex(x);
                Object key = tableBinding.getRowKey();
                if (row.isTrue()) {                    
                    tableBinding.getSelectedRowKeys().add(key);
                } else {
                    tableBinding.getSelectedRowKeys().remove(key);
                }
            }
            tableBinding.setVar("item");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.renderResponse();
        }

    }
```